Error when attempting to set a UITextField to first responder
I get this error when calling becomeFirstResponder() on a
UITextfield:

-[RTIInputSystemClient remoteTextInputSessionWithID:performInputOperation:]  perform input operation requires a valid sessionID. inputModality = Keyboard, inputOperation = , customInfoType = UIEmojiSearchOperations

When I initially create the textfield with this code:
textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size:frame.size))
textField.text = ""
textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
textField.layer.borderWidth = 0
textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
textField.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

And then set textField.becomeFirstResponder(). It works but if I tap off of the textfield I get the error above, and I get the same exact error when I attempt to  tap the text field again. I've already attempted to turn of auto correct as was suggested in a similar post but that does nothing.
I've tried removing the textfield from the superview and creating a completely new one and adding that in it's place and I get the same error

What if you don't do all that hanky-panky with the background color?

no difference no matter how I create the textfield

Could you try the code this way?
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

var textField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupTextField()
}

func setupTextField() {
    textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 40)))
    textField.delegate = self
    textField.text = ""
    textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 0
    textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    textField.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    self.view.addSubview(textField)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

 }

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event:UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true) // Dismiss the keyboard when tapping outside the text field
   }
 }


DispatchQueue.main.async {
self.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
seems to have fixed the problem

Wuju, perfect !
